# Container that I can loop through and access elements via key? C++

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, containers, deque

Is there a container that I can access its element via key AND position?

Pretty much, is there some sort of mix between elements and vectors/deques..?

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard container type for this.

You could use a combination of a `std::map` for key access, and a `std::vector` for position access. If you wrap them together in one class with accessor functions, you can make sure that whenever you insert a new element, both indexes are updated, avoiding inconsistencies.

If you are happy to use the Boost library, it provides a convenience template for these kinds of things. It's called `boost::multi_index`, and it provides for a lot of flexibility, with many different ways to access the same underlying data.

An example of a combination along the lines of what you described, i.e. with string-keys as well as sequence position-based access, is found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/example/sequenced.cpp).

The main data type is declared as

```
typedef multi_index_container<
  std::string,
  indexed_by<
    sequenced<>,
    ordered_non_unique<identity<std::string> >
  >
> text_container;
```

This defines an index with two access types: `sequenced<>` (i.e. by insertion position) as well as `ordered_non_unique<identity<std::string>>`, which is similar to a `std::multimap<std::string,...>`.